# Refresh Indicator issue

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

At some point when i will trigger my refresh indicator there's some kind of shadow?

I've noticed that this issue only appears on iOS devices.

```
 Scaffold(
          body: RefreshIndicator(
            color: Theme.of(context).progressIndicatorTheme.color,
            edgeOffset: 20,
            
            onRefresh: fetchData,
            child: ..........
```

[image: When i am pulling down this indicator]

Comment: This was a known issue and fixed in the latest version or in master channel for now atleast https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/141850